# Is it possible to insert page divs into jQuery mobile page using append()?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

In order to load a jQuery mobile page using an anchor tag, one just gives the page div's id as the href

```
<a href="#page2">My link</a>
<div data-role="page" id="page2">
    <div data-role="header"></div>
    <div data-role="page"></div>
    <div data-role="footer"></div>
</div>
```

But this assumes that the page div was already loaded into the DOM. What if you want to generate pages and put them into the DOM like so:

```
$("body").append(newPageDivHTMLString);
```

I am trying to do it but keep getting a "Cannot call method _trigger of undefined".

Stepping through the jQuery mobile (beta 1) source code, I found on line 2600 the following code:

```
page = settings.pageContainer.children( ":jqmData(url='" + dataUrl + "')" );
```

where pageContainer is the HTML body element and dataUrl is my page div's id. This computes to undefined and seems to be the source of my problem. Is it possible currently to insert a page div into a jQuery mobile page, in the manner that I am?

Thanks for reading a long question. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just tested on my local machine and this works for me:

```
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0b1/jquery.mobile-1.0b1.min.js"></script>

<script>

function create_page(page_name) {
    $('body').append('<div data-role="page" id="' + page_name + '"><div data-role="content">Some content in here.</div></div>');
    //EDITED OUT, SEE BELOW $.mobile.changePage($('#' + page_name));
}

</script>
</head>
<body>



<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="content">
<a href="javascript:create_page('test_page_name');" data-role="button" style="padding:15px; font-size:30px;">TEST TEXT</a>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

----EDIT----
also have this function:

```
function change_page(page_name) {
   $.mobile.changePage($('#' + page_name));
}
```

and use it to change to the dynamically created pages like so:

```
<a href="javascript:change_page('test_page_name');" data-role="button" style="padding:15px; font-size:30px;">Change Page</a>
```

There was some strange behavior with trying to link to the dynamically created page using a hash (href="#test_page_name"). In firebug I saw that the create a page function properly appended the new page onto the body, but the change page button would create another page with the same id as the original page but a data-url that was set properly. The data-role=page div created by clicking on the change page link also had the same content as the first div, and the page created by the create_page function was just ignored.

Comment: That's not quite what I'm doing. The anchor tag needs to have an href=#divid. Clicking it shouldn't trigger a call to changePage, because using an existing page div's id in as the href will cause JQM to do that by itself.

Comment: I tried out your code, modified it so that one button inserts the div and a second button has the id of the new div as its href. Clicking on the second button causes a transition back to the same page as before http://jsfiddle.net/SLejh/

Comment: I guess I don't quite get what you're trying to do. You can trigger that $('body').append(...); on document ready, then you can link to it with a hash driven href (i.e. #divid). Example: $(document).ready(function() {
    $('body').append('<div data-role="page" id="test_id"><div data-role="content">Some content in here.</div></div>');
});

Comment: This is a problem I have in a larger application. I have a footer nav bar. Going to different main pages triggers append() calls for subpages, and creates a list in the main page. The list items are anchor tags with hrefs = #subpagedivids ... sorry if I'm not making much sense, can't provide a link either...thanks for your help

Comment: I see so you're building a list of links that the user can click, but you don't want to force them to view the page right away. See my edit above.

Comment: Nope. Doesn't work. The $.mobile.changePage method call itself leads to the same error that is "Cannot call method _trigger of undefined"...bug in JQM?

Comment: Odd. Worked on my end in FF5 and IE9/8/7

Comment: Actually, never mind, you're right...I was doing $.mobile.changePage(divId), not $.mobile.changePage($(divId))...thank you so much for all your help. Although it's still not the answer I wanted, it is an answer :). I still think just <a href="#divid"> should work...you shouldn't have to call a separate function